# How does a Dapp integration works?

Tags: web3py, web3-react

I am pretty much new in Dapp, I know python, and apart from it I have learned how to make a website on React with backend as Django Rest. But while starting with web 3, I am pretty much confused as if it is possible to make a frontend on React and connect it with web3.py file some how? Or is it some other way to interact in both of the types.

Answer (score 0):

As a newcomer myself I have found an absolutely amazing course online that will help you in all things related to Web3. I am not a shill for the content or in any way affiliated with the project but merely want to recommend it to fellow newcomers.

Please find the following link: [Blockchain Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMwXuJrbJQ&t=64101s)

This course goes into great detail starting from the absolute basics of web3 (including Solitidy for the creating of smart contracts) and ending with a full stack development using React/NextJs. I hope this helps!

Good luck on your endeavors.